# Find overdrawn accounts in SQL

Tags: sql

Hey guys, I have a program that allows me to run queries against a large database.
I have two tables that are important right now, Deposits and withdraws.  Each contains a history of every user.  I need to take each table, add up every deposit and withdraws (per user), then subtract the withdraws from the deposits.  I then need to return every user whos result is negative (aka they withdrew more then they deposited).
Is this possible in one query?
Example:

```
Deposit Table:

|ID|UserName|Amount|
|1 |  Use1  |100.00|
|2 |  Use1  |50.00 |
|3 |  Use2  |25.00 |
|4 |  Use1  | 5.00 |
```

WithDraw Table:
|ID|UserName|Amount|
|2 |  Use2  | 5.00 |
|1 |  Use1  |100.00|
|4 |  Use1  | 5.00 |
|3 |  Use2  |25.00 |

So then the result would output:
|OverWithdrawers|
|      Use2     |

Is this possible (I sure don't know how to do it)?
Thanks for any help,
Max

Comment: For what database?  ANSI syntax may be standard, but implementation varies from vendor to vendor...

Comment: What database and version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.UserName
FROM
(
    SELECT UserName, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
    FROM WithDraw
    GROUP BY UserName
) T1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT UserName, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
    FROM Deposit
    GROUP BY UserName
) T2
ON T1.UserName = T2.UserName
WHERE T1.Amount > COALESCE(T2.Amount, 0)
```

The COALESCE is so that it also works if there are users that have withdrawn but never deposited.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method:

```
SELECT UserName, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM (
    SELECT UserName, Amount
    FROM Deposit
    UNION ALL
    SELECT UserName, -Amount
    FROM WithDraw
) AS U (UserName, Amount)
GROUP BY UserName
HAVING SUM(Amount) < 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Corrected working version:

```
Select innersql.UserName from (
    select 
          d.username,
          SUM(d.Amount) as depositamount,
          SUM(w.WithDraw)as withdrawamount 
    from deposit d
    inner join withdraw w
    on d.UserName = w.UserName
    group by d.UserName
     ) as innersql where depositamount > withdrawamount
```

Comment: above answear from matt is better because of using having

Comment: This also returns the wrong answer. It returns use1 instead of use2.

Comment: Sorry, i used less than instead of greater than, corrected it

I also got a question:

As i see, the primary key in the tables is the ID and shouldn´t it be ID and Username ?